# Why doesn't Mercurial Eclipse auto-add files like Subclipse?

Tags: mercurial

What is the use case for this behavior, which has made my work unavailable from one location to the next on a dozen occasions? Why is hg like this? How am I "not in the know"?

Answer (score 3):

Hg behaves like svn in this case: it only tracks the files that were explicitly added with `svn add` or `hg add` command.

But eclipse plugins behave differently. Why - you could ask their authors.

Comment: Thanks for putting up with my frustration and giving me a good answer. Yeah, I noticed that Subclipse doesn't actually auto-add, but it shows a "change star" on folders with added files. That hg eclipse doesn't do this is making me ultra paranoid whenever I get up to go work somewhere else. Exactly what source control is NOT supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

Zerkms says it as it is - the Eclipse plugin follows the Mercurial standard behaviour.

However, you can enable the option '**preselect tracked files in commit dialog**' in the preferences to get default-to-add on commit. :)